# remove lines from file that does not have dot extension in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, lines

I am having such of file that contains lines as below:

```
/folder/share/folder1
/folder/share/folder1/file.gz
/folder/share/folder2/11072012
/folder/share/folder2/11072012/file1.rar
```

I am trying to remove these lines:

```
/folder/share/folder1/
/folder/share/folder2/11072012
```

To get a final result the following:

```
/folder/share/folder2/11072012/file1.rar
/folder/share/folder1/file.gz
```

In other words, I am trying to keep only the path for files and not directories.

Comment: `[[ -f "${line}" ]] && echo "${line}"`

Comment: If you are using find, use `-type f`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could to use the find command to get only the file list

```
find <directory> -type f
```

Comment: but this does not reply to the request itself ... and yes, the post need to be rewrite if the  real question is toi find real file and folder and not modifying a text file

Answer (score 1):

This

```
awk -F/ '$NF~/\./{print}'
```

- splits input records on the character "/" using the command line switch `-F`
- examines the last field of the input record `$NF` (where `NF` is the number of fields in the input record) to see if it DOES contain the character "." (the `!~` operator)
- if it matches, oputput the record.

Example

```
$ echo -e '/folder/share/folder.2/11072012
/folder/share/folder2/11072012/file1.rar' | mawk -F/ '$NF~/\./{print}'
/folder/share/folder2/11072012/file1.rar
$
```

NB: my microscript looks at `.` ONLY in the filename part of the full path.

*Edit* in my 1st post I reversed the logic, to print dotless files instead of dotted ones.

Answer (score 0):

With **awk:**

```
awk -F/ '$NF ~ /\./{print}' File
```

Set `/` as delimiter, check if last field (`$NF`) has `.` in it, if yes, print the line.

Comment: assuming files are dot name and folder not.

Answer (score 0):

Text only result

```
sed -n 'H
$ {g
:cycle
   s/\(\(\n\).*\)\(\(\2.*\)\{0,1\}\)\1/\3\1/g
   t cycle
   s/^\n//p
   }' YourFile
```

- Based on file name and folder name assuming that:

  - line that are inside other line are folder and uniq are file (could be completed by a OS file existence file on result)
  - line are sorted (at least between folder and file inside)
- posix version so `--posix`on GNU sed